# Submitting form with 100 <select>s to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a pretty basic page that shows every five minutes of the day (12:00, 12:05, 12:10, etc). Next to each time is a dropdown `<select>` with the numbers 1-9. The name of the `<select>` is the name of the time it corresponds to. The user selects one of the numbers, goes to the next, selects a number, etc. until they get to the bottom and hit submit.

In the database table, each time of the day has its own row, with another field for the number.

How can I submit this form and have it insert the number based on the time of day to the proper row? I can't wrap my head around this for some reason. I don't even need to do validation. This is not a live website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the name of the select should be `times[]` and the value should be the time.

so in php you can loop through the `times[]` array and get the row that corresponds to its value.  Then update the count accordingly.

```
<select name="times[]" multiple>
  <option value="19:00">1</option>
  <option value="19:05">2</option>
</select>
```

In php psuedo code

```
foreach ($_GET['times'] as time) {
  *sanatize
  select row where time = time
  update count
}
```

Comment: That might be a problem, because right now the HTML looks like: <label>12:20</label><select name="12:20"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>. Then it repeats to the next time. Because for each time, the user can select a specific number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table like this:

```
MyValues
TimeOfDay varchar(50),
Value int
```

And your posted form data looks like this:

```
?19:00=1&19:05=2
```

You will loop through each posted form field and use the key and value of each field to generate an update statement like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
update MyValues set Value = $value where TimeOfDay = $fieldName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems @dm03514 is good options, but had rather use the `$_POST` than `$_GET`, and on the process you can do like this

```
for($=0;$i<count($_POST['times']);$i++){
     #do some action with $_POST['times'][$i]
}
```